# php fields should not display going to previous page

Tags: php

In a form containing all fields name, address, email, checkbox, date, etc. When I go back all the field values are displayed in each of the above mentioned field. It should not show the field values typed. Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Show us code to help you with..
Hire freelancer if you need worker..

Comment: This is most likely browser behaviour. Try adding `autocomplete="false"` to your input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:-

```
<form action="demo.php" autocomplete="on">
  Name:<input type="text" name="name1"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remembering inputted values is a function that browsers implement to save users time. It's called back forward caching. If you insist on having it reset you can listen for an event called `pageshow` and use a script to clear your form:

Example in jQuery:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    // Clear your form
});
```